# How to convert value types returned by the MethodInfo.Invoke method, to their proper type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, methodinfo

I'd like to invoke a method that returns a `struct`, using the `MethodInfo.Invoke` method. However, the returned variable's type of this metod is `object`, which cannot be cast to a `struct`.

(found that, as well as the suggestion to switch from `struct` to `class`, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7tch9h0(VS.90).aspx )

So how could I cast the (value) result of the invoked method to it's proper type?

(I've tried simple cast as well, but it threw an InvalidCastException)

Here are some chunks of my code:

```cs
public class MyInvokedClass
{
    public struct MyStruct
    { ... };

    public MyStruct InvokedMethod()
    { 
        MyStruct structure;
        ... 
        return structure; 
    }
}

public class MyInvokingClass
{
    // Same structure here
    public struct MyStruct
    { ... };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        ...
        MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod(methodName);
        MyStruct result = (MyStruct)methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, null); 
        // the line above throws an InvalidCastException
    }
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Please excuse me for posting my code incompletely: the two classes are in different namespaces, different projects, that's why I have declared the struct twice. I've tried moving it outside of the classes, but there are different namespaces. I've tried using the same namespace, but the cast would stil not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast fails because they are different types, more specifically one is `MyInvokedClass.MyStruct` and the other is `MyInvokingClass.MyStruct`.

When `InvokedMethod` gets called the `MyStruct` refers to the type nested inside the `MyInvokedClass`, but the when the cast is performed `(MyStruct)` refers to the type nested inside the `MyInvokingClass`.

You could use `MyInvokedClass.MyStruct` inside `MyInvokingClass`to refer to the correct struct, but even better is just to have one `MyStruct` type.

You may find useful to read more about declaration space:

[C# Basic Concepts—Declarations](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Basic_Concepts%E2%80%94Declarations)

Comment: Thank you for your reply... In the "C# basic concepts", it is written that "namespace-member-declarations within namespace-declarations that have the same fully qualified namespace name are members of a single combined declaration space", but, though I have two namespaces with the same name (in different projects) I can stil not cast a member of one namespace to the identically declared member of the other... I guess the best method to solve this is to use a common file with only this type's declaration...

Comment: You are correct, if you have two assemblies you can move the core types that will be used by both assemblies to a third assembly in order to reference it and work with the same type, making the cast succeed.

Answer (score 3):

You have two different types: `MyInvokedClass.MyStruct` and `MyInvokingClass.MyStruct`.

The method you're invoking presumably returns `MyInvokedClass.MyStruct` and you're attempting to cast it to a `MyInvokingClass.MyStruct`. You're hitting the `InvalidCastException` because those are two completely different types.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem, move the structure out of the classes:

```
public struct MyStruct
{ ... };

public class MyInvokedClass
{
    public MyStruct InvokedMethod()
    { 
        MyStruct structure;
        ... 
        return structure; 
    }
}

public class MyInvokingClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        ...
        MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod(methodName);
        MyStruct result = (MyStruct)methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, null); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, that should have worked, had I not declared the classes in different namespaces. Excuse me for posting the code incomplete. And thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @loanna: Namespaces don't have anything to do with it. You can put MyInvokingClass in namespace A, MyInvokedClass in namespace B and MyStruct in namespace C.

Comment: Yep, it was all about different assemblies, not namespaces. Thanks to your posts I've now read more about them (which I should have done before). Thank you!